# Trying to upload to 000WebHost database but doesn't upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload, webserver

I'm trying to upload a pdf file in my Web Host database but it doesn't work .
I have a php file : **upload.php**

```
<form action="<?php print $PHP_SELF?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   Last name:<br /> <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br />
   class notes:<br /> <input type="file" name="classnotes" value="" /><br />    
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Notes" />
</form>

<?php
    define ("filesplace","uploads/"); //uploads is the folder in my server database 

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['classnotes']['tmp_name'])) {

    if ($_FILES['classnotes']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
      echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
   } else {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['classnotes']['tmp_name'], filesplace."/$name.pdf");
  if ($result == 1) echo "<p>Upload done .</p>";
  else echo "<p>Sorry, Error happened while uploading . </p>";
    } 
  } 
?>
```

It shows that the file is being uploaded but in the end it shows the error message : *Sorry, Error happened while uploading*

The file upload.php has all the permissions (777) as well as the *uploads* folder has.
Im am a free client in 000Webhost , this could be a problem ?
Could you please help me with that situation? :D

Comment: What does this have to do with databases? If nothing, please edit your title.

Comment: can you please guide me so I can upload a specific file to my server (I mean /public_html/uploads) ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *"Im am a free client in 000Webhost"* - IMHO and others am sure; feel that that is a terrible hosting service and isn't worth paying for if you expect a better service.

Comment: I have to use this hosting service , and i can't buy a premium service for now , so any solutions ?

Comment: I join @JayBlanchard cause he's right. If you really need help please don't forget to give details with error reporting like Fred-ii- suggested.  So back to you question, what is your variable $PHP_SELF ?